# Make spans in div horizontally scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a container div (fixed width, float left) and a set of spans (fixed width and height) inside the container.

```
<div id="cont">
    <span class="box">1</span>
    <span class="box">2</span>
    <span class="box">3</span>
    ...
</div>
```

While reaching the width of the container, the spans are broken to a new row. How can I make them stay in one row next to each other and have the area scrollable horizontally?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1e3ztnu/).

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add [`white-space:nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)  to `#cont`:

> The white-space CSS property is used to to describe how white spaces
>   inside the element is handled.
>
> nowrap collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks
>   (text wrapping) within text.

```css
#cont {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box {
  background-color: #BBBBBB;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 4px 5px 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <span class="box">1</span>
  <span class="box">2</span>
  <span class="box">3</span>
  <span class="box">4</span>
  <span class="box">5</span>
  <span class="box">6</span>
  <span class="box">7</span>
</div>
```

---

Comment: How to have #cont size to width of parent?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to your container div

fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/g1e3ztnu/3/

Answer (score -1):

You are setting a width in the #cont. Remove the width: 500px to width : auto; If you want to force it with the widht you have you must set a new rule: white-space: nowrap.

Option 1 - CSS

```
#cont {
    overflow:auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

Option 2 - CSS

```
#cont {
    overflow:auto;
    width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g1e3ztnu/2/)